# PHP link problem

Tags: php

I'm trying to display a link orange when clicked but for some reason I can get it to work when using PHP can some one help me correct this problem?

Here is the PHP code.

```
function category_tree( $parent = 0, $parent_url = '' ){
    $page_url = current_page_url();//grabs url address

    echo "<ol>";
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $q = sprintf("SELECT id, category, url FROM categories WHERE parent_id = %d ORDER BY category asc", $parent);
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $q);
    while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r) ){
        $url = $parent_url . $rs['url'];
        echo '<li> <a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $rs['category'] . ' Category Link" ';

        if($url == $page_url){
            echo 'style="color: orange;"';
        }

        echo '>' . $rs['category'] . '</a> </li>';
        category_tree($rs['id'], $url);
    }
    mysqli_free_result( $r );
    echo "</ol>";
}
```

Output:

```
Arts & Humanities
Autos
Business
Computers & Technology
Creative Writing
Education
Entertainment
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading your code, I would try to print the values of $url and $page_url and see if they are ever the same. Also have a look at your output and see if style="color:orange;" is ever being outputted to the browser. If the link are not turning orange, I would imagine that your condition of "($url == $page_url)" never returns true.

**Older answer**

This isn't exactly a PHP problem, it's more to do with the CSS. If you have a CSS file you can add the following to make it work properly:

```
a:link{
   color:black;
}
a:visited{
   color:orange;
}
```

If you need to create a place to put your CSS you can add the following code to your HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* CSS CODE HERE */
</style>
```

Comment: They are the same values $url and $page_url.

Comment: Can you post the output of the browser?

Comment: Post what output the links urls?

Comment: Yes, that way you can see if the browser is actually adding the orange css color stuff or its not even getting to that point in the PHP.

Comment: You need to hit "view source" and then paste the raw output of the browser.